# Is there a way to wrap a div around a text input/textarea consistently in all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying this css:

```
.twrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 0 26px 0;
}
```

And using it in the html like this:

```
     <div class="twrap">
      <input type="text" id="textline" name="textline" value="some text">
     </div>
```

And...

```
     <div class="twrap">
      <textarea id="textbox" name="textbox">some other text</textarea>
     </div>
```

This works almost correctly as desired but not consistently on all browsers. It seems to work correctly on all `input type="text"` fields but there is a discrepancy for it working on `textarea` fields. On some browsers it has a visable 4 pixel space at only at the bottom. The top, left and right sides are consistent as desired.

I have looked into browser sniffing in order to tweak the css for only textarea fields in effected browsers, but this is a bit of a lost cause due to the unpredictable responses and dire recommendations in never to do this.

I've also attempted to normalise the css but this has made no difference. Does anyone have a way I can achieve this reliably?

I have created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ogqaL62p/ so it can easily be viewed on different browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used flex instead of display inline block and gave it a fixed width wrapper. Thus, the textbox in it will retain its width in all cases.

```css
.twrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 0 26px 0;
  width: 300px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

input[type='text'] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="twrap">
  <textarea id="textbox" name="textbox">some other text</textarea>
</div>

<br>

<div class="twrap">
  <input type="text" id="textline" name="textline" value="some text">
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting idea - does resolve the weird gap at the bottom but using `display: flex` breaks the objective by spanning the full width of the container and not wrapping to all four sides of the input. Unless you specify a width - which I would rather not have to do on a case by case basis with inline css. This is why I was using `display: inline-block` to begin with.

Comment: .... though after thinking about it a little more, it may be easier to implement than I first thought. Will give it a go and respond here again.

Comment: It works with a little fiddling on the css side to compensate for variable width fields. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.